# Getting trouble installing HPjmeter

Tags: centos, java, monitoring, out-of-memory

I'm trying to install HPjmeter console on centos 7 desktop in order to monitor my web app GC status . I've follwed all the steps mentioned on the official user guide but when executing this command line in order to launch the console:

```
/opt/hpjmeter/bin/hpjmeter
```

I'm getting this message:

```
Please check that a display is available and the appropriate display variable is set
```

I changed the value of $DISPLAY variable as *localhost:0.0* but still getting the same message.

can any one help me please to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting the DISPLAY you might want to try to run the command: `xhost +`